# Call a method just after a view from nib is loaded and shown on the screen

Tags: ios

i want update my core data database when the view is just loaded on the screen, i know the default method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

that are call when the view is loading, or when disappear, but my question is, exist a default method like the above method or exist a way to call a method just after the view is loaded on the screen, and i see my graphics? not when the display is still black because it's loading...

Comment: view did appear. if it's too fast put some delay in it with [self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Here is the place where you should call your function.
}
```

but be advised: when you update your coredata in the mainthread, your interface will be blocked for the duration of the update.

Comment: yes i now i wanna use this: NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new]; to create another thread, it's the right choice?

Comment: you could just use: `    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doStuff) withObject:nil];
`